# Store in PouchDb without need of revision

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB to store values that come from a database (values sent by the server) but also for some values that are only set by the user from front-side (and so should stay local).

Those front-side values should persist accross multiple connections to the app. That's why I store them in PouchDB.

Since I don't care about the revision system (only one user can modify them from one location - its browser), I'm wondering if there is a way to tell PouchDB to say so. I know there is a `force` parameter for calls, but there is still a need for `_rev` property in those cases...

Is there a way to get rid of the notion of revision and conflict for one table ?

Cheers

Comment: Valentin, have you ever figured it out? Thanks

Comment: nope, and to be honest, that's quite long time ago now, I don't remember how I "solve" my problem :(